# Create table based on user input

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Working with Access 2010 and have limited SQL/VB knowledge. Have a make table query which will copy data from main table and create a backup of that table using the name user inputs.

SQL from SQL view:

```
SELECT [Current Year].ID, 
[Current Year].Returning, 
[Current Year].LastName, 
[Current Year].FirstName, 
[Current Year].[Anticipated Arrival Date], 
[Current Year].Position, 
[Current Year].Email, 
[Current Year].State, 
[Current Year].[21+ yes/no], 
[Current Year].[Will turn 21 while here?], 
[Current Year].[Driver yes/no], 
[Current Year].International, 
[Current Year].[Person requesting background check be run], 
[Current Year].[Cost Center], 
[Current Year].[Account Code to charge for BG checks], 
[Current Year].[Project Code], 
[Current Year].[Emailed CBC (date)], 
[Current Year].[Received Release Form (date)], 
[Current Year].[Ran Background Check], 
[Current Year].[Emailed reminder (date)], 
[Current Year].[Emailed Staff DHS (date)], 
[Current Year].[Received DHS Forms (date)], 
[Current Year].[Mailed/Fax DHS Forms (date)], 
[Current Year].CBCcom, 
[Current Year].ICHAT, 
[Current Year].[Driving Record], 
[Current Year].[Voluntary Discl], 
[Current Year].DHS, 
[Current Year].[DHS Not Needed], 
[Current Year].Notes, 
[Current Year].[No] INTO [Year being backed up?]
    FROM [Current Year]
    ORDER BY [Current Year].LastName, [Current Year].
firstname;
```

Want the user to be prompted to enter the year (2018,2019, etc.) and use that as the actual table name?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the SQL.

Table names and field names cannot be passed as parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Was kind of afraid of that with research I had already done. Wasn't sure if I had been comparing 'apples to apples'.